# Undeclared identifier `histogram`

Tags: plot, styles, histogram, pine-script

When I write the following code, I get an error. But it works at version 3.

```
//@version=4
study("Plot Deneme 2", overlay=false)
plot(close, linewidth=2, style=histogram)
```

> Error: line 3: Undeclared identifier `histogram`

Answer (score 0):

Always read the documentation by `Ctrl + Click (PC)` or `Cmd + Click (Mac)` on the function. [This](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_plot) page seems not to be updated.

`style` parameter (as well as some others) of the `plot()` function has been changed.

It now takes the following types:

> Possible values are: plot.style_line, plot.style_stepline,
>   **plot.style_histogram**, plot.style_cross, plot.style_area,
>   plot.style_columns, plot.style_circles. Default value is
>   plot.style_line.

Comment: Baris, v4 refman is now at: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/

v3 refman is at: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v3/

v4 usrman is here: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/index.html